# Not valid TIFF data! (no 0x4949 or 0x4D4D)

Tags: angularjs, tiff

I am using Filestack in an AngularJS app. when I upload an image I see this

`Not valid TIFF data! (no 0x4949 or 0x4D4D)`

In my console.log. I have done some searching but can not find a solution. Has anyone else had this issue and if so how did you fix it?

Comment: Is the image valid as a TIFF? Does it open correctly. and without warnings, in, say Photoshop and IrfanView (it's a good idea to get a second opinion)?

Comment: the images can be .png, .jpeg, .jpg, .gif and yes they open in photoshop

Comment: If you take one of the problem files, modify its metadata slightly in Photoshop, save it, and then upload it again, do you still get the error? Getting Photoshop to re-write the metadata *might* correct the file. If you look at [exif.js](https://gist.github.com/christopherdebeer/3743287) from line 476, you will see that a 0x4949 or 0x4D4D is *required* as an indicator of TIFF data.

Comment: Also, are you *sure* that the file was correctly uploaded? You can get [extended debug information.](https://www.filestack.com/docs/image-transformations/debug) which includes the file size.

Comment: Looks like it is happening after filestack crops the image

Comment: That would be something to contact Filestack about.

Comment: Yes I have submitted a ticket. Thank you for your help

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Please come back and let us know the result of the support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

After talking with Filestack they are going to turn off that console.log from their APi